# Return image in base64 from rest service to img src tag

Tags: java, html, image, rest, base64

I have a little problem with loading an image in base 64 format.

In the frontend I have: 
   `<img src="/path/to/rest/image">`

The rest service represents:

```
@GET
@PublicResource
@Produces("image/*")
@Path("/path/to/rest/image")
public Response getResource() {

    CacheControl cacheControl = new CacheControl();
    cacheControl.setMaxAge(86400);
    cacheControl.setPrivate(true);
    //image.imputStream() is the stream of the image's base64 representation
    Response.ok(image.getInputStream())).cacheControl(cacheControl)
                    .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=86400").build();
}
```

It returns correct base64 and when I parse it to image in any parser it shows the image. But the img tag still shows that the image is broken. 
Any ideas how to fix it ? Probably I have to add some headers.

Answer (score 1):

Prepend the following text to base 64 returned from rest service

```
data:image/png; base64,
```

Comment: The image might be of any other type than JPEG. Please check

Comment: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN... It's png.

Comment: So change it and try

Comment: Also you need to return base64 of image as a string not as a stream. Also Check if you are getting base64 string in HTML of page

Comment: I tried with both png and jpeg and also return string but still not and not.

Comment: Try setting media type of response to text/plain

Comment: Returning as string or stream?

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET
@Path("/users/photo")
@Produces("image/*")
public Response getPhoto(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @QueryParam("userKey") String userKey) {
    String photo = getStaffPhoto(NullUtils.empty(userKey));
    String mime = photo.split(",")[0].split(":")[1].split(";")[0];
    byte[] data = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(photo.split(",")[1]);
    return Response
            .ok( data, mime )
            .build();
}
```

Maybe that piece of code will help a bit. I store photos in DB as Strings which look like "data:image/gif;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABIAAD/4RF...." They are fetched by userKey with getStaffPhoto() method.

On the client side the code looks like

```
<script>
   var getImage = function(userKey) {
       var userPhoto = getBaseUrl() + "/users/photo?userKey=" + userKey; 
       return "<img src='"+ userPhoto + "'/>";
   }
</script>
```